# Is $[0, 1]^\infty$ bounded?

Tags: general-topology

As the title says. I know this should be an easy/basic fact but I can not find any reference online that explains yes/no and why. In particular, I can not wrap my head around this because of the following: from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set#Definition), a set is bounded iff it is has a lower and upper bound, which are members that are bigger or smaller than any other element of the set. I cannot see why this should not hold for infinite dimensions. Can anybody explain how to think about this problem? (My background is not in mathematics, so forgive me if this is a very easy question).

Comment: **What** is $[0,1]^\infty$?

Comment: What metric are you using?  The answer depends on the metric

Comment: "from wikipedia, a set is bounded iff it is has a lower and upper bound": this holds only for subsets of $\Bbb R$. However, your set is not a subset of $\Bbb R$, thus this question is ill-posed. To formulate a meaningful question, you need to specify what is the metric space where you consider $[0,1]^{\infty}$.

Comment: You didn't read that wikipedia page far enough, you read only the heading [Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set#Definition) which gives a limit version of the definition of bounded applying only to the real numbers. Look at the next heading [Metric Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set#Metric_space). (I've [changed those headings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set), which were misleading).

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define what you mean by $[0,1]^{\infty}$. Let's go with the "smallest infinity" and assume you meant 
$$[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}=\{f:\mathbb{N}\to[0,1]\}$$
Then this is not an ordered space. So "lower" and "upper" bound does not make sense. You would need some sort of metric (i.e. distance) which tells you how far apart from each other elements are. And then you can define bounded as: There exists a constant C such that for any two elements $f_1,f_2$ from your set $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$, the distance $d(f_1,f_2)<C$ is smaller C.

For example one metric could be 
$$d_\infty(f_1,f_2)=\|f_1-f_2\|_\infty=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |f_1(n)-f_2(n)|$$
The distance is the supremum of all distances, and that is of course bounded by 1, since they all have to be in [0,1]. But if your metric is different, then you might not get that this set is bounded. For example summing all the differences will not give you finite distances. Although this would not define a metric on the entire space, since even the distance between two elements can be infinite which violates the definition of a metric.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, a set $S$ is **bounded** if there's some finite number $M$ such that no two objects $x,y$ living in $S$ are further apart than $M$. To measure "further apart" you need a **metric**, which tells you the distance $d(x,y)$ between them.

There are **multiple ways** of giving a metric on $[0,1]^\infty$. (In fact, on any non-empty set, including just $[0,1]$!)

- The simplest to describe is known as the $\ell_\infty$ metric, and says that the distance between $x$ and $y$ is $d(x,y)=\sup_a{|x_a - y_a|}$ - roughly the largest component-wise difference of $x,y$. Given this metric, your space is indeed bounded -- clearly $d(x,y) \le 1$ for any $x,y$.
- It is more awkward (though mathematically trivial) to describe an example of a metric for which this is unbounded. One stupid example is as follows. Let $T = \left\{(1,1,\ldots,),(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\ldots),(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\ldots),\ldots\right\}$. We take $d(x,x)=0$ for any $x$, and $d(x,y) = 1$ for $x\neq y$ and $x,y$ not in $T$. Now declare that $d((\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},\ldots),(\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{m},\ldots)) = |n-m|$ and $d(x,(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},\ldots)) = n$ otherwise. Clearly there are points arbitrarily far apart, and the set is now unbounded.

The point is that $x =(1,0,\frac{4}{7},0.5124,\pi/4,0,0,\ldots)$ is just an arbitrary name for an element of an abstract set, and there's nothing to say it should be close to or far from $y =(1,0,\frac{4}{7},0.5125,\pi/4,0,0,\ldots)$. That's extra structure which you choose to add.

Note that the naive notion of distance fails to be a metric:

- Suppose you tried to define $d(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum_a (x_a - y_a)^2}$. Now $x=(0,0,0,\ldots)$ and $y=(1,1,1,\ldots)$ have $d(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum_a 1}$ is not well-defined!